# Verify exact number of invocations within verifyOrder

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

I want to verify that a number of functions were called in a specific order, but one of the functions gets called N times:

```
verifyOrder {
    myMockObject.func1()
    (exactly = 10) myMockObject.func2()
    myMockObject.func3()
}
```

How do I specify the "exactly = 10" above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. Your best option would be `verifySequence`, which verifies that the calls happened in a specified sequence.

```kotlin
verifySequence {
   myMockObject.func1()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func2()
   myMockObject.func3()
}
```

It is not pretty, but to my knowledge, you have no better alternative.

Comment: Thanks. And for future readers wondering what is the difference between verifyOrder and verifySequence, I've just researched it and I think verifyOrder allows other calls to happen in between those being verified, while verifySequence does not.

Comment: Exactly. `verifySequence` is an exact match while `verifyOrder` just checks that those calls respect the given order, but other calls may be omitted from `verifyOrder`. Good point @k314159 ;)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. The official docs are a bit vague on that distinction.